# Wireless is always disabled, cant unable it

Tags: release-loki, wifi, internet

I just upgraded from Feya to Loki and I really like it! There is just one thing thats not working properly on my computer. With my wlan stick connected i can turn on wireless, but instead of listing the networks it still says "wireless is disabled; enable wireless to discover nearby wireless access points." The funny thing is in the beginning everything worked smoothly but after turning wireless on and off one time it stopped working.
Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Thank you all!

Comment: Share the output of "sudo rfkill list" in order to help you

Answer (score 1):

Without info regarding what Wireless adapter you are using, we really cannot help you that much.

You can try reloading the driver for the wireless adapter using:

```
sudo modprobe -v <wireless driver>
```